# Create a wide view of a database table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table which stores attributes about different physical objects. It has the following fields:

```
object_name
attr_name (string e.g. attr_1, attr_2 etc.)
attr_value (number)
date_modified (date)
priority (integer)
```

There may be many different values for the same `attr_name`, which will be added at different dates and with different priority level (representing the accuracy of the source), so I need this structure for traceability later.

I would like to create a view of this table so that I can query it in an efficient way for multiple (~100) attributes e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM View1 WHERE attr_1 = 5 and attr_2 > 3 etc.
```

So in order to do this, I think I need a view with fields like:

```
object_name
attr_1
attr_2
etc.
```

Each attribute `attr_x` should contain the highest priority version of the attribute from the original table. Does anyone know how to do this? I only know very basic SQL so I don't even know what this is called or if it is possible. Has anyone done this before, in any SQL-type database? I'd like to avoid having 2 separate tables if possible. Happy to accept any other solution which accomplishes both the traceability and the fast querying requirements.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would do a good job explaining what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example query that returns the all the values with the highest priority in the format that you want:

```
SELECT
    object_name,
    (SELECT attr_value AS attr_1
     FROM t
     WHERE t.object_name=t1.object_name AND attr_name='attr_1'
     ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT attr_value AS attr_2
     FROM t
     WHERE t.object_name=t1.object_name AND attr_name='attr_2'
     ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object_name FROM t) t1;
```

I assumed that the table is called `t`. The query returns 2 `attr_???` columns. If you have more, you have to add more subqueries, one for each column. If you don't like that (e.g. because you have a large number of `attr_name`), then we can do something that does not require to write a huge query but it will return the results as JSON objects (so it will be in different format).

If you want to create a view, just run the following:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT ...
                      ^^^ insert the query from above
```

If you need this to be as fast as possible, I would recommend using 2 tables: one for the highest priority values and one for everything else.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much! I can generate the query in Python based on the list of attributes I already have so not a problem. Thanks for the tip on speed - I'll see how quick it is with one and create a new high-priority table if necessary.